# Question about adversarial robustness

Tags: machine-learning

Recently I was studying about adversarial robustness. There are some thing I am seeking knowledgable person for help.

I think the gradient descent may be the reason that the model is not robust to adversarial attack and also lead to convergence problem of adversarial training.

Because the gradient descent selects dw with the steepest decrease of loss in condition of input of x, which means with any small perturbation of x, the loss will be greater than the loss without perturbation.

The robuestness problem should be

find dw to    minimize(  max{ loss(y0,f(x+dx)) : w=w+dw}  )

However, for adversarial training it is actually trying to find max{loss(y0,f(x+dx))} in condition of w but not w+dw.

So the conseqence is that after the following step when w is update to w+dw, the true value of dx to max loss(y0,f(x+dx) is already changed.

and loss(y0,f(x+truedx))) > loss(y0,f(x+dx))) and the thus max(loss(y0,f(x+truedx))) is not minimized in efficient way and will lead to more difficulty in deceasing with iterations.

Is there any mathmatical way to calculation dw to make sure max(loss(y0,f(x+dx))) in condition of w+dw can be reduced in the steepest way.